# how to conditional render a button on header options on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to change the background color of a button on the header navigation, depending on if the condition is true or false. This is the button :

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: () => <BackButton />,
        headerRight: () => (
          <Button
            text="Agregar gasto"
            onPress={formik.handleSubmit}
            buttonColor={disabledButton ? 'tomato' : 'cyan'}
            height={pixelPerfect(33)}
            width={pixelPerfect(150)}
            marginHorizontal={28}
            color={COLORS.white}
            iconName="plus"
            iconColor={COLORS.white}
            paddingVertical={1}
          />
        ),
      });
    })();
  }, [disabledButton]);
```

and this is the condition :

```
const disabledButton = () => {
    return formik.values.total === "0" && formik.values.type === "" && formik.values.date === null; 
  }
```

it is always true although I change the data. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `disabledButton` as a value instead of calling the function. A function is a truthy value, this is why the expression is always true.

This is how it should be:

```js
buttonColor={disabledButton() ? 'tomato' : 'cyan'}
```